# Mercurial Output Local Public Revision

Tags: mercurial

I would like a command to output the largest public revision number in my local repo

This command does what I want, but takes 2 seconds to come back with '43067', so I would think there would be a more direct way

`hg log -l 1 -r "sort(public(), -rev)" --template "{rev}"` takes 2 seconds

For comparison `hg log -l 1 -r "public()" --template "{rev}"` returns '0' instantly

---

Edit 10 minutes later:

`hg log -l 1 -r "reverse(public())" --template "{rev}"` seems acceptably fast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go with:

```
hg id --num --rev 'last(public())'
```